# Left and right derivative of composition

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $f(x)=y$ and $g(y)$ be two functions such tat $f'_+(x)$(right sided derivative exists) and  $g'_+(x)$ (right sided derivative exists) let $h(x)$ be a function that is defined as $h(x)=g(f(x))$ is the right sided/left sided derivative must exist ?

Does the "chain rule" works on one sided derivatives and I can simply calculate 
$h'_+(x)=g'_+(f(x))\cdot f'_+(x) $ ???

Answer (score 1):

Neither need exist.  Let g(y) be the step function at 0, so 1 for all non-negative numbers, and 0 for negative ones.  It has a right-handed derivative but not a left-handed one.  Let f(x) be $-x^2$.  Then $g(f(x))$ is not even continuous at 0!